# iPad App design decision

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I would like to develop a reader app for viewing and manipulating proprietary format documents. The documents are 2D. (Might add some cool page flip effects) The interface is similar to that of mobile safari. I'm trying to decide whether to write this in Quartz2D or OpenGL ES. I have no prior experience with either of those. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no prior experience then Quartz2D would be much easier to learn than OpenGL. And for a reader app, OpenGL is most likely overkill anyways, unless you need to do really heavy rendering.

Comment: how would I do the page flip effect with Quartz2D?

Comment: UIView has animation methods. You can use setAnimationTransition:forView:cache with the UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipLeft/UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipRight transition types: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine a text centric app that would be much enhanced by OpenGL unless you want to draw text on the side of cube or something.

Comment: I presume iBooks uses OpenGL  for both the facing text / images and the bleed-through text / images on pages that wave about in real time as you push them around with your finger.

Comment: CA (Core Animation) uses OpenGL under the hood. Pretty sure they're using CA for iBooks. Use the standard frameworks + CA for any fancy animations.

Comment: You'd be surprised what Quartz can do. A lot of animations that look like GL are actually Quartz. In any case, there is seldom any reason for none game apps to go to GL first. 95% of the time you can use the the higher level non-GL API.